# Getting a List of IDs from a Table with Group Concat as a variable to uise for IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table of `locations` and a table of `stockLevels`. I working on a complex query to tell me items which have been in stock for a long time, which location they're in and a few other things all in one hit.

Part of it is giving me inaccurate results though.

```
... LEFT JOIN ...
SELECT id, sum(stockLevel) as totalStockLevel FROM stockLevels 
    WHERE stockLocation IN 
        ((SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(id, CHAR(8))) as idList 
            FROM `locations` WHERE  `isThirdParty`  = '0' 
            AND `pickFrom`='1' 
        GROUP BY pickFrom)) 
    GROUP BY id) 
ourStock ON ourStock.id=products.id
... MORE OF QUERY ....
```

This is a snippet of the whole query, the inner `SELECT` works in isolation, but it's not applying the list of IDs into the IN clause, seems to just read the first one.

So, to explain more clearly.

The inner `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(id, CHAR(8))) as idList 
    FROM `locations` WHERE  `isThirdParty`  = '0' 
    AND `pickFrom`='1' 
GROUP BY pickFrom
```

Return a comma separated list value as a column named `idList`, the value being `1,2,10,11`

This query works.

If I manually use that comma separated list in the original query, it also works, ie:

```
... LEFT JOIN ...
SELECT id, sum(stockLevel) as totalStockLevel FROM stockLevels 
    WHERE stockLocation IN 
        (1,2,10,11) 
    GROUP BY id) 
ourStock ON ourStock.id=products.id
... MORE OF QUERY ....
```

No errors are generated by this code, but the results it produces are that of this query:

```
... LEFT JOIN ...
SELECT id, sum(stockLevel) as totalStockLevel FROM stockLevels 
    WHERE stockLocation IN 
        (1) 
    GROUP BY id) 
ourStock ON ourStock.id=products.id
... MORE OF QUERY ....
```

So, I'm not getting the comma separated list generated by the inner query being injected into the IN clause of the outer query.

Can anyone advise why?

Comment: I experienced the same thing you referred to where use of a SELECT inside of IN() meant only one record was 'read'/worked with.  I ended up using stored procedures.  I used the relevant SELECT statement within the CALL statement to pass the list of ids I wanted to work with based on comma separated values stored in a single row within a different table.  Like this:  CALL ExampleProcedureName(SELECT csv FROM `some_table` WHERE id = 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN()` expects a list of values or a subquery, but you are giving it a varchar. You migh try to join stockLocation and Locations to produce desired results:

```
SELECT stockLevels.id, 
       sum(stockLevels.stockLevel) as totalStockLevel 
  FROM stockLevels 
 INNER JOIN locations
    ON stockLevels.stockLocation = locations.id
   AND locations.isThirdParty = '0'
   AND locations.pickFrom = '1'
 GROUP BY stockLevels.id
```

Of course, you might eliminate group_concat to get the same effect:

```
WHERE stockLocation IN 
    (SELECT id
       FROM `locations` 
      WHERE `isThirdParty` = '0' 
        AND `pickFrom`='1' 
    )
```

Comment: The second option didn't work, but the first one's nailed it! Thanks

Comment: @JamieHartnoll It has to work, but oh well. Perhaps you have missed closing parenthesis? I'm glad this worked out :-)